# What is "Premium Regional" fare for MTS Compass Card?

Tags: usa, transit, public-transport, california, san-diego

From [this page](https://www.sdmts.com/fares-passes) (also [this page](https://www.sdmts.com/what-fare-do-i-need)):

```
Adult 1-Day Pass        $6 /$12 Premium Regional
```

What does "Premium Regional" stand for, and how is the premium regional fare different from the standard fare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On [this page](https://www.sdmts.com/fares-passes/compass-cash) it explains that some services require a "Premium Pass"

> Trips that include the COASTER or Rapid Express require a Premium Regional Day Pass

I'm picking that the standard Regional Pass does not include the COASTER or Rapid Express.

Additionally, from [this page](https://www.sdmts.com/fares-passes/fare-change-sept-1-2019)

> **What is the difference between the Regional and Premium Regional passes?**
>
> The Regional Day/Monthly/30-Day passes are valid on most MTS and NCTD bus and trolley/SPRINTER services. The Premium Regional Day pass also includes travel on the MTS Rapid Express/Premium routes 280/290 and NCTD Flex (except 372).  The Premium Regional Monthly/30-Day pass also includes the MTS Rapid Express/Premium routes 280/290 and the rural services. There are no upgrades from the Regional Pass for the rural/premium service.

Comment: It's a bit strange that the second page doesn't mention the COASTER.